# Prove that if sin$A < \frac ab$ and $a > b$, then $\angle B$ is acute.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

Given $\triangle ABC$, $a > b$ and $\angle A$ with the property that sin$A < \frac ab$. How do I prove that $\angle B$ is an acute angle?

I'm  trying to use this and proof that a triangle with this particular property isn't included in the ambiguous case of the sine law.

I'd really appreciate any help.
[image]

Comment: The statement is false. You might think about accepting an answer that shows why it is false (e.g. Pythagoras' answer), rather than one that tries to show it is true.

Comment: @robjohn I'm sorry but there's been some confusion regarding my question.

Comment: If you're given that $a\gt b$, say that rather than giving it as a conclusion of something else (a conclusion which doesn't follow, so it seems to have been ignored).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not true. See the diagram below:

[image]

---

**Comments on the Edited Question**

As mentioned in comments under Pythagoras' answer, it is true that if $a\gt b$, then $A\gt B$. To show this, consider the [incircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle) of our triangle:

[image]

Looking at the right triangles $\triangle OEC$ and $\triangle OEB$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
a
&=CE+EB\tag{1a}\\
&=r\cot(C/2)+r\cot(B/2)\tag{1b}
\end{align}
$$
Looking at the right triangles $\triangle ODC$ and $\triangle ODA$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
b
&=CD+DA\tag{2a}\\
&=r\cot(C/2)+r\cot(A/2)\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, if $a\gt b$, then $\cot(B/2)\gt\cot(A/2)$, which, since $\cot(\theta)$ is decreasing on $(0,\pi/2)$, says that $A\gt B$.

Therefore, since the sum of the three angles must be $180^{\large\circ}$, $B$ must be less than $90^{\large\circ}$; otherwise, the sum of $A$ and $B$ would be greater than $180^{\large\circ}$.

Comment: Is there a way for me to prove that is true?

Comment: I have added a proof. It uses the definition of cotangent and the fact that it is a decreasing function on $(0,\pi/2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your picture is misleading. If $\angle C$ is obtuse, then $\angle B$ is necessarily acute.

In general, your statement is false: Take $a=c=1$ and $b=\sqrt{3}$. Then $\angle A=\angle C=30^\circ$ and $\angle B=120^\circ$ with $$\sin(A)=\frac 1 2<\frac 1{\sqrt{3}}=\frac a b.$$

Comment: i see, but will my statement be true if a > b?

Comment: If $a>b$, then you can easily show that $\angle A>\angle B$. Then it follows that $\angle B$ must be acute, since the sum of the three interior angles equals $180^\circ.$

Comment: (+1) I used a different example in my answer ($1,\sqrt2,\sqrt5$), but your example works just as well. Yours was first, but I guess the picture got more attention.

Comment: @robjohn You presented the idea more friendly. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

Let $CD\perp AB$ where $D$ lies on $AB$. Then, $\sin A=\frac {CD}{b}<\frac ab\implies CD< a$. Now in $\triangle BCD$, $CD<a\implies \angle B<\angle CDB\implies \angle B <90^{\circ}$ (Because the opposite angle of the larger side is greater than the opposite angle of the smaller side in a triangle). Hence, $\angle B$ is acute.

[image]

Comment: How do I know that CD < a? I'm a little confuse

Comment: @Mohammadmuazzamali $\triangle ACD$ is a right triangle. According to the definition of sine, we have $\sin A=\frac{\text{opposite side of $\angle A$}}{\text{hypotenuse}}=\frac{CD}{b}$. Now since we are given that $\sin A<\frac ab$, we can write $\frac{CD}{b}<\frac ab$. We can now multiply both sides of the inequality by $b$ to get $CD<a$. Do you get it now?

Comment: However, $\angle CBD$ might be supplementary to $\angle CBA$, not equal.

Comment: @robjohn Yes, I saw your answer and the other comments. Thanks for finding the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sine laws` to prove this:

From the sine laws we know: $$\frac{\sin{A}}{a} = \frac{\sin{B}}{b} = \frac{\sin{C}}{c}$$

But we only need: $$\frac{\sin{A}}{a} = \frac{\sin{B}}{b}$$ because side `c` and angle `C` are not required for this question.

Then, rearrange the terms to find a similarity with the question: $$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{\sin{A}}{\sin{B}}$$

But, $$\sin{A} < \frac{a}{b}$$ so, $$\sin{A} < \frac{\sin{A}}{\sin{B}}$$
Now remove the like terms,

--> $\sin{A} < \frac{\sin{A}}{\sin{B}}$

--> $1 < \frac{1}{\sin{B}}$

--> $\sin{B} < 1$

Comment: $\sin(B)\lt1$ for all $B\ne\frac\pi2$, so this does not show that $\angle B$ is acute.

Comment: @ robjohn♦ What do you mean? That is the meaning of acute < 90˚ and this method proves that it is $B < 90˚$

Comment: No, you have shown that $\sin(B)\lt1$, but that does *not* show that $B\lt90^{\large\circ}$

Comment: @robjohn♦ yeah, but why not? If $\sin{B} < 1$, shouldn't $B < \arcsin{1}$

Comment: $\sin\left(150^{\large\circ}\right)=\frac12$, but $150^{\large\circ}\gt90^{\large\circ}$

Comment: @robjohn♦ Yes but, I am just solving each side separately ($\arcsin{1} = 90˚$), and $B > 90˚$ would not work, as the inequality of $\sin{A} < \frac{a}{b}$ would not hold true.

Comment: Look at the triangle in my answer. $\sin(A)\lt\frac ab$, yet $B$ is not acute.

Comment: @robjohn♦ Actually, you're correct! Sorry, I did not see it the other way...